# how can split the string in java and using in spinner in android

Tags: android-spinner

I am an android developer, I am trying to split the input string, divide the state and city and using the two spinners when lode the state in first spinner corresponding city can load to the second spinner.

ArrayList arrayList1 = new ArrayList();
private String[] arr,arr1;

String input= "Tamilnadu-Chennai,Madurai,Trichy~Kerala-Kochi,Trivandrum~Karnataka-Bengaluru,Mangalore";
arr = input.split("~");

```
    for (String output: arr) {
       // Log.e("output1",output);

        arr1 = output.split("-");
        for (String output2 : arr1) {
            Log.e("output2", output2);
           arrayList1.add(output3);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,arrayList1);
            s1.setAdapter(adp);
        }


    }



}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String sp1= String.valueOf(s1.getSelectedItem());
    Toast.makeText(this, sp1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(sp1.contentEquals("Income")) {

    }
    if(sp1.contentEquals("Expense")) {

    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

Comment: What are the expected keys and values in your spinner?

Comment: states are in one spinner and the cities are in one spinner, like Tamilnadu, Kerala, Karnataka, all are in one spinner and corresponding  cities are another spinner when I select the Tamilnadu in the first spinner corresponding cities load in the second spinner

Comment: Please include the _exact_ output you expect here.

Comment: Tamilnadu-Chennai, Madurai,Trichy~Kerala-Kochi,Trivandrum~Karnataka-Bengaluru,Mangalore
 You need to separate States (Marked as) and cities(Marked as)
 Create two spinners named State and city.
 If you select State Tamilnadu in spinner 1 then Chennai, Madurai, and Trichy should populate in spinner 2. (Populate city according to state selection)